# Multibib in TeXclipse

Tags: bibtex, multibib, texlipse

I am using TeXlipse 1.5.0 on miktex 2.9 on Windows 7, and I try to use the package `multibib` to create multiple bibliographies. I however can't seem to get TeXlipse to run bibtex on multiple bibliographies. This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{Prim,Sec}%
{Primary References,%
Secondary References}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Introduction}

My primary literature is \citePrim{RefWorks:7142},
\citePrim{RefWorks:7143}, and \citePrim{RefWorks:7144}). My secondary literature is
\citeSec{RefWorks:7141}.

\bibliographystylePrim{plainnat}
\bibliographyPrim{IntroBib}

\bibliographystyleSec{plainnat}
\bibliographySec{IntroBib}

\end{document}
```

and my bibtex file `IntroBib.bib` is:

```
@article{RefWorks:7144,
     author={Franklin Allen and Douglas Gale},
     year={2000},
     title={Bubbles and crises},
     journal={The economic journal},
     volume={110},
     number={460},
     pages={236-255}
}
@article{RefWorks:7142,
     author={John M. Quigley},
     year={2001},
     title={Real estate and the Asian crisis},
     journal={Journal of Housing Economics},
     volume={10},
     number={2},
     pages={129-161}
}
@article{RefWorks:7143,
     author={John M. Quigley},
     year={1999},
     title={Real Estate Prices and Economic Cycles},
     journal={International Real Estate Review},
     volume={2},
     number={1},
     pages={1-20}
}
@article{RefWorks:7141,
     author={John B. Taylor},
     year={2009},
     title={The financial crisis and the policy responses: An empirical analysis of what went wrong},
     journal={NBER Working Paper}
}
```

I have made it work in TeXworks, with the following batch file:

```
@echo off
FOR %%A IN (*.aux) DO bibtex %1\%%A
```

with the argument $directory, but I would really prefer getting it to work in TeXlipse. I have tried to implement [this solution](http://sourceforge.net/p/texlipse/discussion/451976/thread/3519d637) but `bibtex` is not run on the prim.aux and the sec.aux. Any help appreciated!